# Case-insensitive substring search in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, string

How can I write a shell script that will do a case-insensitive substring match of command output?

Comment: `grep -i` may be?

Comment: How will I put that inside my script? I'm sorry if this is a novice questions. I'm just starting to study Linux because I need it for my internship. Thanks!

Comment: *question. Sorry for the grammatical error.

Comment: What you're asking about is **shell scripting** -- "linux" is not a programming language, it's an operating system kernel.  The shell most commonly used with linux is `bash`, which is a superset of the [unix standard `sh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_command-line_interpreters#Unix-like_systems).  You might start by looking at one of these: [|1|](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) [|2|](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) -- just to get a grip on what the actual context is.

Comment: My bad. I was confused between Linux and bash. Thanks for the links!

Comment: Is there some reason this question is still on hold?

Comment: This question now seems quite clear and matches the guidelines in the help center. Can it please be opened for the benefit of others?

Comment: I don't see the fuzz why this question is not clear. What should I add for it to be clear?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First here's a simple example script that doesn't ignore case:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(echo hello) == hello ]; then
    echo it works
fi
```

Try changing the string hello on the right, and it should no longer echo `it works`. Try replacing `echo hello` with a command of your choosing. If you want to ignore case, and neither string contains a line break, then you could use grep:

```
#!/bin/bash
if echo Hello | grep -iqF hello; then
    echo it works
fi
```

The key here is that you are piping a command output to `grep`. The `if` statement tests the exit status of the rightmost command in a pipeline - in this case grep. Grep exits with success if and only if it finds a match.

The `-i` option of grep says to ignore case.
The `-q` option says to not emit output and exit after the first match.
The `-F` option says to treat the argument as a string rather than a regular expression.

Note that the first example uses `[ expression ]` which allows direct comparisons and various useful operators. The second form just execs commands and tests their exit status.

Comment: I don't understand why Gilles felt it was necessary to change the code I contributed. He didn't break anything but it worked just fine. You don't need the double quotes in this example - they are important if the output contains spaces however. And == works just as well as = because sh is actually bash on Linux. The original Bourne Shell is long gone at this point in time. I don't think even Solaris ships it any more. While unnecessary in this example I agree that double quotes are probably a best practice, but so is '==' in my opinion, to keep assignment and comparison clearly separate.

Comment: Wait, so one can edit a post? I did not know that.

Comment: With sufficient reputation, yes. I would hope somebody with high reputation would think twice before making needless edits however, particularly to code in this forum. http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: @BobDoolittle It may be in [certain cases](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18828196) it makes a difference but not with your setup - it's good to know.

Comment: Note that `==` is non-standard and non-portable. Use `=` instead. `grep -q` should be preferred over redirecting to /dev/null (unless you don't want the command to be killed by a SIGPIPE) as then `grep` stops processing as soon as it finds a match (imagine the case of a command outputting gigabytes and `hello` being found on the first line). The `-q` option is standard. 20 years ago, it would not have been portable, but now it's universal.

Comment: Note that in practice, it's not only  about the Bourne shell. `==` is not POSIX. `sh` is not `bash` on all Linux based systems. `==` is not supported by `ash` (upon which the `sh` of many BSDs and Debian derivatives at least is based), or `posh`, and needs quoted in `zsh`. There's no point doubling the `=`. `[` is a command for testing. There's no need to disambiguate between assignment and comparison here. That's different in `(( a == b ))` vs `(( a = b))`. Using `==` in a script that starts with `#! /bin/sh` is wrong. If you assume `ksh` or `bash` syntax, update the `#!` accordingly.

Comment: Very helpful to know, thanks. Post updated to reflect bash. Since bash accepts == I believe it makes for more readable code so will leave as-is.

Answer (score 57):

You can do case-insensitive substring matching natively in `bash` using the regex operator `=~` if you set the `nocasematch` shell option. For example

```
s1="hElLo WoRlD"
s2="LO"

shopt -s nocasematch

[[ $s1 =~ $s2 ]] && echo "match" || echo "no match"
match

s1="gOoDbYe WoRlD"
[[ $s1 =~ $s2 ]] && echo "match" || echo "no match"
no match
```

Comment: lol! points for obscure shell knowledge.

Comment: This option also affects the simple match operator. `[[ XYZ == xyz ]] && echo "match"` => `match`

Answer (score 9):

For a case-sensitive string search of the value of the variable `needle` in the value of the variable `haystack`:

```
case "$haystack" in
  *"$needle"*) echo "present";
  *) echo "absent";
esac
```

For a case-insensitive string search, convert both to the same case.

```
uc_needle=$(printf %s "$needle" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' ; echo .); uc_needle=${uc_needle%.}
uc_haystack=$(printf %s "$haystack" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' ; echo .); uc_haystack=${uc_haystack%.}
case "$uc_haystack" in
  *"$uc_needle"*) echo "present";;
  *) echo "absent";;
esac
```

Note that the `tr` in GNU coreutils doesn't support multibyte locales (e.g. UTF-8). To make work with multibyte locales, use awk instead. If you're going to use awk, you can make it do the string comparison and not just the conversion.

```
if awk 'BEGIN {exit !index(toupper(ARGV[2]), toupper(ARGV[1]))}' "$needle" "$haystack"; then
  echo "present"
else
  echo "absent"
fi
```

The `tr` from BusyBox doesn't support the `[:CLASS:]` syntax; you can use `tr a-z A-Z` instead. BusyBox doesn't support non-ASCII locales.

In bash (but not sh), version 4.0+, there is a built-in syntax for case conversion, and a simpler syntax for string matching.

```
if [[ "${haystack^^}" = *"${needle^^}"* ]]; then
  echo "present"
else
  echo "absent"
esac
```

Comment: I realize this is a couple years old, but all that `printf | tr` makes my head spin around. Where possible, keep your invocation of commands to a minimal ... given a variable v, you can accomplish the same thing using `v=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<$v)`. For those who have never seen it before, the `<<<` is essentially a "here variable" like the use of `<<EOF` is for a here document. Don't `printf` or `echo` unless you absolutely have to do so.

Comment: @Will That only works in shells that have the `<<<` operator: ksh, bash, zsh, but not plain sh. And it's pretty close to piping from `printf` in terms of how it runs: there's the same number of calls to `fork` and `execve` (assuming that `printf` is built-in, which is the case on most common shells); a difference is that `<<<` creates a temporary file rather than using a pipe. `<<<` is convenient to type but not a performance improvement.